# Angular project Token removal when browser is closed

Tags: c#, .net, angular, jwt

I have an angular project and I provide token based login in this project. When the user exits using the exit button, I delete the current token from the database, but I cannot delete it when the browser is closed directly. How can I do this?

**Handler Code:**

```
public async Task<IResult> Handle(LogoutCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
            {
                var isThereAnyUser = await _userRepository.GetAsync(u => u.UserId == request.UserId);
             
                isThereAnyUser.Token = "";
                isThereAnyUser.RefreshToken = "";
                _userRepository.Update(isThereAnyUser);
                await _userRepository.SaveChangesAsync();
                return new SuccessResult(Messages.logOutMessage);


            }
```

**Wep api Code:**

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Logout([FromBody] LogoutCommand logoutCommand)
        {
            var result = await Mediator.Send(logoutCommand);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                return Ok(result.Message);
            }
            else
            return BadRequest(result.Message);
        }
```

Comment: There are cookie types which only persist during the session, therefore will be gone when you restart the browser if you want this.

Comment: Thank you, but my goal is to prevent login from different devices at the same time, so if there is an active token, I do not allow it to create a new one. I took care of this in the backend, it works, but as I said, when I close the browser, I get into trouble.

Comment: It will be hard to get this working in all cases and accross a variety of browsers. How about giving the tokens an expiration time and updating the expiration every time the token is used to access the API. If a user does not hit the Exit button, the token expires; until then the user cannot access the API. Therefore the expiration time should be short (5 minutes?)

Comment: What you said makes sense, but it doesn't seem to work as it generates tokens for the user while logging in. To summarize my purpose again, I want to prevent login to an account from 2 different devices. Like you can't log in from another device without logging out of one device. @Markus

Comment: @AkgzEren I've moved the proposal to an answer and extended it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be hard to get this working in all cases and accross a variety of browsers, so you'd need a backup solution anyway that takes care of token expiration.

As an alternative, you could give the tokens an expiration time that is stored in the database and update the expiration every time the token is used to access the API.

The process could be outlined as follows:

- user logs in: if there is no valid token, a token is created with Login Time + 5 minutes. Otherwise, the login is refused.
- user accesses the API (with the token): Token is updaten with access time + 5 minutes (if there are no API accesses, the Angular app could periodically call the API to extend the token)
- user logs out: Token is deleted; user can immediately log in on another device
- user does not log out but closes the browser: Token expires after 5 minutes; until then the user cannot use the API from another device. Therefore the expiration time should be short (5 minutes in this example)

As an alternative to storing the expiration time in the database, you could also store it in the token, but you'd need to exchange tokens upon API request (or with the periodic calls).

Comment: I've been thinking since morning, my brain was on fire. After reading it again and again, I understood what you said. Thank you very much for your help. I'm going to implement it right now.